# How to filter on an object in JavaScript correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am keying off of a permission ID and trying to filter an object that has those permissions. This is a concise version of the JSON object

```
[
  {
    "id": "INS-SH-V",
    "name": "View Sharing Functionality",
    "description": "Access to view Email and Schedule windows",
    "group": "Sharing",
    "scopeable": false,
    "featureId": "INS-BE",
    "scopeExclusions": null,
    "dependsOn": null
  },
  {
    "id": "INS-SH-U",
    "name": "Manage Sharing Functionality",
    "description": "Access to send emails and schedule jobs",
    "group": "Sharing",
    "scopeable": false,
    "featureId": "INS-BE",
    "scopeExclusions": null,
    "dependsOn": [
      "INS-SH-V"
    ]
  }
 ]
```

Basically I am given `INS-SH-V` and want to scan all the items in every `dependsOn` attribute, if `INS-SH-V` is there then I want to return the `id` of that object. Is there a simple way to do this? I have been dying trying to get it to work on a for-loop.

Thanks!

This was my attempt so far:

```
let len = this.props.permissions.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++){
      if (this.props.permissions[i].dependsOn[0] !== null){
        // return this.props.permissions[i].id // Should return INS-SH-U
        if (permissionId === this.props.permissions[i].dependsOn[0]){
          // return this.props.permissions[i].id
          console.log(this.props.permissions[i].id);
        }
      }
    }
    return null;
```

Comment: Please show what research you've done into solving this yourself, and what attempts you've made.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Hello sorry -- I've added my attempt at the solution on the newest edit. 

But I see that there is a more concise solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filter` in order to filter your array and then use map to get the id only:

**EDIT: Added includes**

```
const checkId = 'SOME ID'
const ids = yourData.filter(obj => obj['dependsOn'] !== null && obj['dependsOn'].includes(checkId)).map(obj => obj.id)
```

Comment: Thanks for this! You are a true life saver.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter` for that and finally `map` the array as you only want the ids.
I added an additional Object that has more than one id in `dependsOn` as an example.

```js
const inputArr = [
  {
    "id": "INS-SH-V",
    "name": "View Sharing Functionality",
    "description": "Access to view Email and Schedule windows",
    "group": "Sharing",
    "scopeable": false,
    "featureId": "INS-BE",
    "scopeExclusions": null,
    "dependsOn": null
  },
  {
    "id": "INS-SH-U",
    "name": "Manage Sharing Functionality",
    "description": "Access to send emails and schedule jobs",
    "group": "Sharing",
    "scopeable": false,
    "featureId": "INS-BE",
    "scopeExclusions": null,
    "dependsOn": [
      "INS-SH-V"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "INS-SH-asdsd",
    "name": "View Sharing Functionality",
    "description": "Access to view Email and Schedule windows",
    "group": "Sharing",
    "scopeable": false,
    "featureId": "INS-BE",
    "scopeExclusions": null,
    "dependsOn": [
        'INS-SH-V',
        'INS-SH-A'
    ]
  },
 ];

const idToCheck = 'INS-SH-V';
const result = inputArr.filter(obj => (obj.dependsOn?.includes(idToCheck) || false)).map(({ id }) => id);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you'd need something like the following

```js
const ids = array.filter(obj => obj.dependsOn && obj.dependsOn.includes('INS-SH-V')).map(cur => cur.id);
```

Comment: `obj.dependsOn` is Array, not string... They will never be equal.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using a for loop,

```js
let data = [{
    "id": "INS-SH-V",
    "name": "View Sharing Functionality",
    "description": "Access to view Email and Schedule windows",
    "group": "Sharing",
    "scopeable": false,
    "featureId": "INS-BE",
    "scopeExclusions": null,
    "dependsOn": null
  },
  {
    "id": "INS-SH-U",
    "name": "Manage Sharing Functionality",
    "description": "Access to send emails and schedule jobs",
    "group": "Sharing",
    "scopeable": false,
    "featureId": "INS-BE",
    "scopeExclusions": null,
    "dependsOn": [
      "INS-SH-V"
    ]
  }
]

function filterByDependsOn(val) {
  let result = []


  for (let obj of data) {
    if (obj.dependsOn && obj.dependsOn.includes(val)) {
      result.push(obj.id)
    }
  }

  return result
}

console.log(filterByDependsOn('INS-SH-V'))
```

If you want a one-liner solution,

```js
let data = [{
    "id": "INS-SH-V",
    "name": "View Sharing Functionality",
    "description": "Access to view Email and Schedule windows",
    "group": "Sharing",
    "scopeable": false,
    "featureId": "INS-BE",
    "scopeExclusions": null,
    "dependsOn": null
  },
  {
    "id": "INS-SH-U",
    "name": "Manage Sharing Functionality",
    "description": "Access to send emails and schedule jobs",
    "group": "Sharing",
    "scopeable": false,
    "featureId": "INS-BE",
    "scopeExclusions": null,
    "dependsOn": [
      "INS-SH-V"
    ]
  }
]

const filteredData = data.filter(el => el.dependsOn && el.dependsOn.includes('INS-SH-V')).map(v => v.id)

console.log(filteredData)
```